# Header text in gridview changed to zero

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am using the below code to get the sum of `DataField="Quantity"` in grid-view and show the result in the grid-view footer

the issue is `HeaderText="Quantity"` is changed to zero

```
protected void griddelverynote_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
     int TotalQuantity = 0;
     if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
     TotalQuantity += Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Quantity"));
     else if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
     e.Row.Cells[1].Text = "Total Quantity";
     e.Row.Cells[2].Text = TotalQuantity.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probelm in your code is that `RowDataBound` event is fired for each row when it is bound. So for each row `TotalQuantity` is getting re-initialized to `0`. Declare the variable `TotalQuantity` outside:-

```
int TotalQuantity = 0;
protected void griddelverynote_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
          TotalQuantity += Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Quantity"));
     else if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
     {
          e.Row.Cells[1].Text = "Total Quantity";
          e.Row.Cells[2].Text = TotalQuantity.ToString();
     }
}
```

Comment: @Ayman - Got it! You were missing the curly braces in the `else if` block. Check the answer.

Comment: the same issue HeaderText=0

Comment: @Ayman - Cz you were missing the code blocks. Check `else if`  part.